# Elastic search query for SQL query

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have SQL table XYZ with below data:

```
P------     S-----     R--  
SAMSUNG     GALAXY     1
SAMSUNG     GALAXY     2
SAMSUNG     GALAXY     10
SAMSUNG     GALAXY     9
APPLE       IOS        12
APPLE       IOS        9
```

I have below SQL query:

`select * from XYZ where P='SAMSUNG' AND S='GALAXY' AND R IN (1,2)`

It returns all the records that match column P with value "SAMSUNG" AND column S with "GALAXY" AND column R with values 1 or 2.

OUTPUT:

```
SAMSUNG     GALAXY     1
SAMSUNG     GALAXY     2
```

Now I am trying to prepare an Elastic Search query for the above behavior but the result is not as expected:

```
{'query': 
       {'bool': 
              {'must': [{'match': {'P' : 'SAMSUNG'}}],
               'must': [{'match': {'S' : 'GALAXY'}}],
               'must': [{'match': {'R' : '1'}}, {'match': {'R' : '2'}}]
               }
        }
}
```

The above query returns empty output. But If I specify only 'P' it works:

```
{'query': 
       {'bool': 
              {'must': [{'match': {'P' : 'APPLE'}}]}
        }
}
```

This returns below output

```
APPLE       IOS        12
APPLE       IOS        9
```

Not sure what is wrong with my first query. Could any one help how to use "must", "should" with elastic search queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a combination of [`bool/must`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) queries, to achieve your result

**`must` is equivalent to the logical `AND` operator and you can use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) that will act as `IN`**. You need to wrap both the match query and terms query inside the `must` clause, as in your SQL query all the conditions are combined using AND operator.

---

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "P": "SAMSUNG",
  "S": "GALAXY",
  "R": 1
}
{
  "P": "SAMSUNG",
  "S": "GALAXY",
  "R": 10
}
{
  "P": "SAMSUNG",
  "S": "GALAXY",
  "R": 2
}
{
  "P": "SAMSUNG",
  "S": "GALAXY",
  "R": 9
}
{
  "P": "APPLE",
  "S": "IOS",
  "R": 12
}
{
  "P": "APPLE",
  "S": "IOS",
  "R": 9
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "P": "SAMSUNG"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "S": "GALAXY"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "R": [
              1,
              2
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67024741",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.8836654,
        "_source": {
          "P": "SAMSUNG",
          "S": "GALAXY",
          "R": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67024741",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.8836654,
        "_source": {
          "P": "SAMSUNG",
          "S": "GALAXY",
          "R": 2
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Great. This worked. Thank You Very Much. If possible could you please point some URL which explains must/should/filter of elastic search queries. I tried some on google search but couldn't get much success.

Comment: Also not sure how you quickly created a working example. If it is an online tool it will be very helpful if you share the URL. Thank You.

Comment: @PJ47 I have not used any online tool :-)

Comment: @PJ47 You can refer to this official documentation, to know more about `must/should/filter` clause --> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: @PJ47 I just searched right now, and I found this tool which you can use to convert SQL query to elasticsearch query https://sqltoelasticsearch.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Thank You. The converter looks great :)